# Being that string substitution is frowned upon with forming SQL queries, how do you assign the table name dynamically?

Tags: python, sqlite

Pretty new to sqlite3, so bear with me here..

I'd like to have a function to which I can pass the table name, and the values to update.

I initially started with something like this:

```
def add_to_table(table_name, string):
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO {table} VALUES ({var})'
        .format(
            table=table_name,
            var=string)
        )
```

Which works A-OK, but further reading about sqlite3 suggested that this was a terribly insecure way to go about things. However, using their `?` syntax, I'm unable to pass in a name to specify the variable.

I tried adding in a `?` in place of the table, but that throws a syntax error.

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ? VALUES (?)', ('mytable','"Jello, world!"'))
>> >sqlite3.OperationalError: near "?": syntax error
```

Can the `table` in an sql statement be passed in safely and dynamically?

Comment: I...can't really see a use case for this...I'm confused by your motivation.  What would you hope to accomplish by doing this?  You should know what table you're inserting data into.

Comment: Use an ORM like sqlalchemy.

Comment: Can you refactor your data so that instead of having a Spam table and an Eggs table, you have, say, a Food table with a type column? (If you don't know the answer to that, maybe post another question with a stripped-down schema and ask how to improve it so you don't need dynamic table selection?) Usually when you think you need dynamic SQL like this, the answer is an incorrect data model. But "usually" isn't "always", and in the rare cases where you have to do it, string formatting is the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not the dynamic string substitution *per-se* thats the problem. Its dynamic string substitution with an user-supplied string thats the big problem because that opens you to SQL-injection attacks. If you are absolutely 100% sure that the tablename is a safe string that you control then splicing it into the SQL query will be safe.

```
if some_condition():
   table_name = 'TABLE_A'
else:
   table_name = 'TABLE_B'

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO '+ table_name + 'VALUES (?)', values)
```

That said, using dynamic SQL like that is certainly a code smell so you should double check to see if you can find a simpler alternative without the dynamically generated SQL strings. Additionally, if you really want dynamic SQL then something like SQLAlchemy might be useful to guarantee that the SQL you generate is well formed.

Comment: You're missing a space between the table name and `VALUES`. (Which is one of many reasons that string formatting is better than concatenation. And, since the OP used `format` in his question, there's no worry that he won't understand it…)

Answer (score 1):

Composing SQL statements using string manipulation is odd not only because of security implications, but also because strings are "dumb" objects. Using sqlalchemy core (you don't even need the ORM part) is almost like using strings, but each fragment will be a lot smarter and allow for easier composition. Take a look at the [sqlalchemy wiki](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/trac/wiki/UsageRecipes) to get a notion of what I'm talking about.

For example, using sqlsoup your code would look like this:

```
db = SQLSoup('sqlite://yourdatabase')
table = getattr(db, tablename)
table.insert(fieldname='value', otherfield=123)
db.commit()
```

Another advantage: code is database independent - want to move to oracle? Change the connection string and you are done.