Writing json to sqlite3 but with a condition to remove a person from sqlite3 if person is not in json file
I have a json file (that's dynamic and is generated daily) which is like this for yesterday:
[
    {"name": "saeed1", "age": 29},
    {"name": "saeed2", "age": 30},
    {"name": "saeed3", "age": 31}
]

And this is my python code to include them in a sqlite file:
with open('my_file.json', 'r') as file:
    names = json.loads(file.read())

filename = "names.sqlite3"
table_name = 'names'
sqlite3_connection = sqlite3.connect(filename)
sqlite3_connection.execute(
    f'''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {table_name}
    (name TEXT,
    date TEXT,
    sent_status TEXT,
    PRIMARY KEY(name)
    );
    '''
    )

for name in names:
    sqlite3_connection.execute(
        f"""
        INSERT OR IGNORE INTO {table_name} (name, date, sent_status)
        VALUES (
        '{name['name']}',
        '{(datetime.datetime.now()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')}',
        'not_yet'
        )
        """
        )

sqlite3_connection.commit()
sqlite3_connection.close()

Now suppose this is my json file for today:
[
    {"name": "saeed2", "age": 30},
    {"name": "saeed3", "age": 31},
    {"name": "saeed4", "age": 32}
]

The difference between the first and the second json file is that saeed1 is removed in the second json output and saeed4 is new.
With the code I have, new names are inserted in the database and because of INSERT OR IGNORE INTO, it doesn't write duplicate exact names.
The question based on the above is: How can I remove saeed1 when I run my python code for today's json file?

Why not just empty the table before you do all the inserts?

Don't use string formatting to substitute variables. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python

@Barmar because I don't want the date field changes from yesterday date to today date. Did I get your mean right?

Your code will also not update the age if it has changed from one day to the next. Is that intended?

Why store age in a DB in the first place? Store the birth date and calculate the age based on the current date. Age changes every year, birth date doesn't.

@Barmar the age does not update. The intention is not to calculate the age. The date column in the sqlite file is updated. I'm adding date to see when a new person is added to the database and do something based on that date value.

@Barmar sqlite3_connection.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (name TEXT, date TEXT, sent_status TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(name) );', (table_name,)), with this I'm getting this error and don't know why: sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error and don't know where's my issue. Also tried with double quotes and removed comma after table_name, but still has error.

You can't use placeholders for table and column names, only values. You have to use the f-sdtring for the table name.

@Barmar that's going to be hard:( So, you suggest to remove the variable table_name and use its value as a normal string in all queries? I think I cannot mix f-string with the old format.

@Barmar I mean something like create table names, insert into names, update names, delete from names`, etc. Is that what you mean?

See the code in my answer. I use the placeholders for the values in the IN (...) list, but I use string formatting to substitute the table name.

@Barmar I see your answer. I was trying to try the given link before using completely your answer.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19193851/being-that-string-substitution-is-frowned-upon-with-forming-sql-queries-how-do

Make a list of all the names that are in the JSON file. Then delete all the rows where the names are not in this list.
all_names = list({i['name'] for i in names})
placeholders = ','.join(['?'] * len(all_names))

sql = f'DELETE FROM {table_name} WHERE name NOT IN ({placeholders})'
sqlite3_connection.execute(sql, all_names)


Thanks a lot. I tried and it worked perfectly as expected (that's because an expert like you wrote the code). But I don't understand the execute query completely. Is it delete from names where name not in saeed2,saeed3,saeed4? I know what I asked and I know what I want, but I'm not sure if I understood the query well.

I mean it checks saeed1 is not in all_names, so it removes it. Then goes to saeed2 and see it is in all_names and skips, and goes through all the names like this. Am I right?

Yes, that's how it works.
